# tab bar goes when going between views

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I am developing a tabbed bar application using storyboards.

I am attempting to put in a back button one a view - but when I press to go back (from one view to another) the tab bar vanishes.

How can I ensure the tab bar stays there?

Comment: are you using storyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you're adding the `UITabBar` to the main Navigation Controller or View Controller of Navigation Hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select Tab Bar on the Navigation Controller Bottom Bar under the Attributes Inspector, then set the bottom bar to Inferred for the rest of your pages (or Tab Bar if you want it to be different on any pages)